# How to reset uploaded file list in Kendo Angular Upload component

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a `kendo-upload` component to upload just one file. After a files is uploaded I need to clear the list or uploaded files.

1. Initial state

   [image: Initial state - before a file is selected]
2. After a file is selected

   [image]
3. After a file was uploaded

   [image]

I need the step 3. to looks like the step 1. = like if I would click on `Clear` button.

I tried to bind to `(success)` event and do:

a. `this.pictureUpload.fileList.clear();`

b. `this.pictureUpload.fileList.remove(this.pictureFilePreview.uid);`

But always get an exception from `uploadService`:

[image]

I did dig into `uploadService` source code and understand why I get an exception. I also looked into `upload-component` source code and tried to understand how to externally execute `Clear` button method, but did not find any easy way. I think I'm over-complicating this and there must be some easy solution I did not spot yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Model binding to do that.

```
  import { FileInfo } from '@progress/kendo-angular-upload';
```

First capture the completed event in kendo-upload:

```
    [(ngModel)]="myFiles" (complete)="uploadCompleted()"
```

Add a member:

```
     myFiles: Array<FileInfo> = [];
```

And capture the event and reset the file list to be empty:

```
 public uploadCompleted(){
    this.myFiles = [];
 }
```

Comment: need to do without ngModal